# Cassandra ec2snitch vs gossippropertyfilesnitch

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

Using Gossip snitch in Cassandra works well in aws single region and multi region Cassandra deployment .What is the real cause for using ec2 snitch or ec2 multi region snitch  in Cassandra cluster deployment in aws other than (they use aws API to get details of the instance).What are the pro's and con's of using gossip property snitch in AWS production?

Answer (score 1):

EC2 snitches should be used only if you're 100% sure that you never will add another DC outside of AWS (but can you be sure in that?).  These snitches just slightly simplify your life by inferring the DC & rack information, instead of specifying it manually as in case of `GossingPropertyFileSnitch` (GPFS).

Pros of using GPFS:

- You can add data centers outside of AWS. For example, to implement hybrid cloud deployments (AWS/other cloud, or AWS/on-premise), or to migrate data out of AWS, ...

Cons of using GPFS:

- You need to specify DC & rack information manually (but I don't believe that it will make a lot of problems - and I think that you can even automate it by asking for meta-information of node when it's provisioned).